# ¿Cómo saber qué parte de una lista que representa un árbol está contenida o similar a otra?

Tags: python, árboles, nlp, spacy

Por ejemplo tengo una oración que puedo analizar como un árbol con `spaCy` y `nltk`.

> *When did Beyonce start becoming popular?*

es el array `treeQuestion[0]`:

```
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 
'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']),
'?_._punct'])]
```

Lo hice con el siguiente código:

```
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>print(treeQuestion)
When did Beyonce start becoming popular?
[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print()  for sent in en_nlp(predicted.iloc[0,3]).sents]

>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>print(treeQuestion)
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
          start              
  __________|___________      
 |    |     |     |  becoming
 |    |     |     |     |     
When did Beyonce  ?  popular
```

Y me gustaría saber si `treeQuestion` está contenido en el siguiente árbol y en que medida se ha mostrado, por ejemplo la siguiente:

```
--- 1 ---
born and raised in houston, texas, she performed in various singing and dancing competitions as a child, and rose to fame in the late 1990s as lead singer of r&b girl-group destiny's child.
[Tree('performed_VBD_ROOT', [Tree('born_VBN_advcl', ['and_CC_cc', Tree('raised_VBN_conj', [Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('houston_NN_pobj', [',_,_punct'])]), 'texas_NN_npadvmod'])]), ',_,_punct', 'she_PRP_nsubj', Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('competitions_NNS_pobj', ['various_JJ_amod', Tree('singing_NN_nmod', ['and_CC_cc', 'dancing_NN_conj'])])]), Tree('as_IN_prep', [Tree('child_NN_pobj', ['a_DT_det'])]), ',_,_punct', 'and_CC_cc', Tree('rose_VBD_conj', [Tree('to_IN_prep', ['fame_NN_pobj']), Tree('in_IN_prep', [Tree('1990s_NNS_pobj', ['the_DT_det', 'late_JJ_amod'])]), Tree('as_IN_prep', [Tree('singer_NN_pobj', ['lead_JJ_compound', Tree('of_IN_prep', ['r&b_NN_punct', Tree('child_NN_pobj', [Tree('destiny_NN_poss', [Tree('group_NN_compound', ['girl_NN_compound', '-_HYPH_punct']), "'s_POS_case"])])])])])]), '._._punct'])]
                                                      performed                                                                                  
  ________________________________________________________|__________________________________________________                                     
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |                       rose                                 
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |     ___________________|_________                           
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                   as                        
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                   |                          
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |                 singer                      
 |   |   |   |   |        |                               |                         |    |         |          _________|_____                     
 |   |   |   |   |       born                             |                         |    |         |         |               of                  
 |   |   |   |   |    ____|_____                          |                         |    |         |         |     __________|_____               
 |   |   |   |   |   |        raised                      in                        |    |         |         |    |              child           
 |   |   |   |   |   |     _____|_______                  |                         |    |         |         |    |                |              
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             in           competitions                   as   |         in        |    |             destiny          
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             |        _________|__________               |    |         |         |    |     ___________|______        
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |          houston    |                 singing         child  to      1990s       |    |    |                group    
 |   |   |   |   |   |    |             |       |          __________|_______       |    |     ____|____     |    |    |            ______|____   
 ,  she  ,  and  .  and texas           ,    various     and              dancing   a   fame the       late lead r&b   's         girl
```

De hecho, como uno puede ver podemos encontrar `rose to fame` que es muy similar a `start becoming popular`. En cuanto a la mitad (3/6) del árbol está aquí podemos decir que 50% se ha mostrado.

Un contraejemplo, uno con un puntaje malo, hubiera sido el siguiente :

```
--- 0 ---
beyoncé giselle knowles-carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ bee-yon-say) (born september 4, 1981) is an american singer, songwriter, record producer and actress.
[Tree('is_VBZ_ROOT', [Tree('carter_NN_nsubj', [Tree('giselle_NN_compound', ['beyoncé_NN_amod']), 'knowles_NNS_compound', '-_HYPH_punct', Tree('say_NN_parataxis', ['(_-LRB-_punct', '/biːˈjɒnseɪ/_-LRB-_amod', Tree('yon_NN_compound', ['bee_NN_compound', '-_HYPH_punct']), '-_HYPH_punct']), ')_-RRB-_punct', '(_-LRB-_punct', Tree('born_VBN_acl', [Tree('september_NN_npadvmod', ['4_CD_nummod', ',_,_punct', '1981_CD_nummod'])]), ')_-RRB-_punct']), Tree('singer_NN_attr', ['an_DT_det', 'american_JJ_amod', ',_,_punct', Tree('songwriter_NN_conj', [',_,_punct', Tree('producer_NN_conj', ['record_NN_compound', 'and_CC_cc', 'actress_NN_conj'])])]), '._._punct'])]
                                                             is                                                                                      
  ___________________________________________________________|________________________________________________                                        
 |                                  carter                                                                  singer                                   
 |      ______________________________|_________________________________________             _________________|_______________                        
 |     |     |   |   |   |     |                        say                    born         |     |      |                songwriter                 
 |     |     |   |   |   |     |       __________________|_______               |           |     |      |     _______________|_________              
 |     |     |   |   |   |  giselle   |         |        |      yon         september       |     |      |    |                      producer        
 |     |     |   |   |   |     |      |         |        |    ___|___     ______|______     |     |      |    |       __________________|________     
 .  knowles  -   )   (   )  beyoncé   (    /biːˈjɒnseɪ/  -  bee      -   4      ,     1981  an american  ,    ,    record              and    actress
```

---

### Actualización 31/08

Encontré una forma de saber cuando un objeto está contenido en otro. Dejo el botín abierto para la persona que pueda decirme cuando un árbol es similar a otro, especialmente a través de sinónimos o. Por ejemplo:

- `rose to fame` for `start becoming popular`
- `start being popular` for `start becoming popular`

#### Transforma una lista en un árbol.

```
class WordTree:
    '''Tree for spaCy dependency parsing array'''
    def __init__(self, tree, is_subtree=False):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param tree: The array contening the dependency
        :param parent: The parent of the tree if exists
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = tree.label().split('_')[0] # the first element of the tree # We are going to add the synonyms as well.
        
        for subtree in tree:
            if type(subtree) == Tree:
                # Iterate through the depth of the subtree.
                t = WordTree(subtree, True)
                t.parent=tree.label().split('_')[0]
            elif type(subtree) == str:
                surface_form = subtree.split('_')[0]
                self.children.append(surface_form)
```

#### Probar si un árbol está contenido en otro

```
def isSubtree(T,S):
    if S is None:
        return True
    if T is None:
        return False
    if areIdentical(T, S):
        return True
    return any(isSubtree(c, S) for c in T.children)

def areIdentical(root1, root2):
    '''
    function to say if two roots are identical
    '''
    # Base Case
    if root1 is None and root2 is None:
        return True
    if root1 is None or root2 is None:
        return False
 
    # Check if the data of both roots their and children are the same
    return (root1.data == root2.data and
            ((areIdentical(child1 , child2))
             for child1, child2 in zip(root1.children, root2.children)))
```

#### Ejemplo

```
# first tree creation
text = "start becoming popular"
textSpacy = spacy_nlp(text)
treeText = nltk_spacy_tree(textSpacy)
t = WordTree(treeText[0])

# second tree creation
question = "When did Beyonce start becoming popular?"
questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
q = WordTree(treeQuestion[0])

# tree comparison
isSubtree(t,q)
```

Aquí probamos dos árboles de dos oraciones donde una es una subparte de la otra. Tenemos entonces `True`. Puede ser interesante encontrar una manera de decir cuando uno está parcialmente contenido en el otro.

Comment: O te has explicado muy mal o no entiendo lo que quieres hacer. ¿Podrías ser más concreto con "cuanto contiene un párrafo en una oración"?

Comment: @Saelyth Sí, lo siento, es mi culpa no ser el primer idioma de habla hispana. Actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: Dices que "rose to fame" es muy similar a "start becoming popular", sin embargo el parecido no es gramatical, sino semántico. Es decir, tú sabes que tienen significados similares, si bien su análisis gramatical puede ser diferente (o aún si gramaticalmente son parecidos, eso no implica que semánticamente también lo sean). Desconozco la biblioteca spaCy, pero ya que trata de análisis del lenguaje natural, probablemente incluya utilidades para buscar parecidos semánticos, que es lo que necesitarías.

Comment: @abulafia Sí, tiene toda la razón, es por eso que quería usar sinónimos con [nltk wordnet](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get-synonymsantonyms-nltk-wordnet-python/) después y agregarlos en cada nodo del árbol antes de hacer las pruebas correspondientes. No conozco toda la biblioteca, y ya no conozco utilidades para buscar parecidos semánticos hoy, que es lo que necesitarío en efecto. Me voy a informar.

Comment: @abulafia En efecto hay [`.similarity()` en spaCy](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity). Intentaré comparar dos textos. Sin embargo, hay uno que es muy largo y el otro que es relativamente pequeño, la pregunta `treeQuestion`.

Comment: Quizás puedas "trocear" el texto largo (sintácticamente, ayudándote del árbol que spaCy genera), y comparar cada "trozo" (sub-árbol) con la frase corta. Creo que más o menos ésto es lo que estabas preguntando.

Comment: @abulafia Sí, acabo de probar con un ejemplo cuyo resultado es [aquí](https://textuploader.com/d2t9s). Calcula la similitud pero no me permitió encontrar el buen resultado hasta ahora. Creo que se debe al hecho de que compara todo el subárbol y de repente no le da tanta importancia al pasaje que responde la pregunta. Voy a probarlo sobre todo el test y ver el rendimiento y luego pensar en la relevancia de la idea de hacer un árbol.

Comment: @abulafia Me acabo de dar cuenta de que la similitud de SpaCy se basa en la similitud del coseno que ya he probado. Realmente quería hacer un enfoque orientado a gráficos.

Comment: Con spacy lo puedes lograr. Si no te da buenos resultados es porque necesitas cargar un modelo del lenguaje, resultado de un corpus de multiples medios escritos, que da como resultado los vectores por cada palabra. El problema tuyo no creo creo que sea el algoritmo de similitud coseno, sino el modelo que estas cargando, que, posiblemente sea el que viene en spacy para ingles.