# ¿Cómo cambiar un array en un árbol?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, árboles, spacy

Tengo un array (`list`) de palabras que representa un árbol creado por SpaCy y me gustaría tenerlo en un formato de arbol con hijos .

```
treeQuestion = [Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
```

He buscado y descubierto tres maneras de hacerlo. Sin embargo no sé lo que esta mejor pero no quiero complicar mi vida para reinventar la rueda. El propósito de estos árboles es poder [comparar fácilmente si un árbol está en otro](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191523/c%C3%B3mo-saber-qu%C3%A9-parte-de-una-lista-que-representa-un-%C3%A1rbol-est%C3%A1-contenida-o-es-s). Entonces, **el resultado esperado** es solo obtener un Arbol para compararlos.

#### ¿Creando la clase de árbol yo mismo?

Por lo momento , inspirándome desde [este sitio](https://python-forum.io/Thread-Convert-tree-to-list-of-lists), hice:

```
class WordTree:
    def __init__(self, array, parent = None):
        #print("son :",array[0][i])
        self.parent = []
        self.children = [] # if parenthesis then it has son after "," analyse : include all elements until the next parenthesi
        self.data = array
        #print(array[0])
        for son in array[0]:
            print(type(son),son)
            if type(son) is Tree:
                print("sub tree creation")
                self.children.append(son.label())
                print("son:",son)
                t = WordTree(son,son.label()) # should I verify if parent is empty ?
                print("end of sub tree creation")
            elif type(son) is str:
                print("son creation")
                self.children.append(son)
            else:
                print("issue?")
                break # prolbem ?
```

Funciona bien al principio, pero cuando encontramos un subárbol tenemos problemas.

```
>>> t = WordTree(treeQuestion, treeQuestion[0].label())
<class 'str'> When_WRB_advmod
son creation
<class 'str'> did_VBD_aux
son creation
<class 'str'> Beyonce_NNP_nsubj
son creation
<class 'nltk.tree.Tree'> (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
sub tree creation
son: (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
<class 'str'> p
son creation
<class 'str'> o
son creation
<class 'str'> p
```

Solo toma las letras del subárbol, no las palabras.

#### ¿Usando Anytree?

Tambien descubrio la librería `anytree`:

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

root = Node(treeQuestion[0]) # es por decir start_VB_ROOT
```

#### O usando tree de la biblioteca nltk?

No sé cómo usar este pero puede ser más fácil usar el material dado por aquellos que hicieron el árbol `treeQuestion`.

```
import spacy
from nltk import Tree


en_nlp = spacy.load('en')

doc = en_nlp("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.")

def to_nltk_tree(node):
    if node.n_lefts + node.n_rights > 0:
        return Tree(node.orth_, [to_nltk_tree(child) for child in node.children])
    else:
        return node.orth_


[to_nltk_tree(sent.root).pretty_print() for sent in doc.sents]
```

Answer (score 0):

Esto funciona con simple ejemplos como `[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]`

```
from anytree import Node, RenderTree

class WordTree:
    '''Tree for spaCy dependency parsing array'''
    def __init__(self, array, parent = None):
        """
        Construct a new 'WordTree' object.

        :param array: The array contening the dependency
        :param parent: The parent of the array if exists
        :return: returns nothing
        """
        self.parent = []
        self.children = []
        self.data = array

        for element in array[0]:
            print(type(element),element)
            # we check if we got a subtree
            if type(element) is Tree:
                print("sub tree creation")
                self.children.append(element.label())
                print("son:",element)
                t = WordTree([element],element.label()) # should I verify if parent is empty ?
                print("end of sub tree creation")
            # else if we have a string we create a son
            elif type(element) is str:
                print("son creation")
                self.children.append(element)
            # in other case we have a problem
            else:
                print("issue?")
                break
```

No logré obtener el resultado por una cosa como :

```
for i,sent in enumerate(sentences):
    i = WordTree(sentences, sentences[0].label())
```