# ¿Cómo obtener el primer artículo de una lista?

Tags: python, python-3.x, array

Tengo un array (`list`) de palabras que representa un árbol creado por SpaCy y me gustaría obtener el primer elemento `start_VB_ROOT` pero no lo obtengo.

```
>>>questionSpacy = spacy_nlp(question)
>>>treeQuestion = nltk_spacy_tree(questionSpacy)
>>>print(treeQuestion)
[Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
```

En efecto cuando hizo `treeQuestion[0]` obtengo :

```
(start_VB_ROOT
  When_WRB_advmod
  did_VBD_aux
  Beyonce_NNP_nsubj
  (becoming_VBG_xcomp popular_JJ_acomp)
```

Queremos `start_VB_ROOT` pero cuando hizo `treeQuestion[0][0]` obtengo `When_WRB_advmod`

Y cuando hizo `print(treeQuestion[0].label)` obtengo:

```
 <bound method Tree.label of Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])>
```

Entonces, si quiero acceder al elemento 1, estoy en IndexError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supongo que los elementos son instancias de `nltk.Tree`, siendo así si quieres acceder a la etiqueta del nodo debes usar el método `Tree.label()`:

```
>>> from nltk import Tree
>>> treeQuestion = [Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux','Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])]
>>> treeQuestion[0].label()
'start_VB_ROOT'
```

Comment: Hmm intentolo y me da `<bound method Tree.label of Tree('start_VB_ROOT', ['When_WRB_advmod', 'did_VBD_aux', 'Beyonce_NNP_nsubj', Tree('becoming_VBG_xcomp', ['popular_JJ_acomp']), '?_._punct'])>` Puesto al dia mi codigo

Comment: No es un atributo, es un método de instancia, te falta llamarlo `print(treeQuestion[0].label())`

Comment: Ha petardo, bien hecho!

Comment: Por cierto, ¿tendrías una idea de cómo cambiar esta lista a un árbol? Trabajo sobre esto [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191978/c%C3%B3mo-cambiar-un-array-en-un-%C3%A1rbol) para comparar oraciones entre ellos, para saber si uno puede ser incluido en el otro.