# ¿Cómo crear diferentes instancias de una clase con un bucle for?

Tags: python, python-3.x, clase

Con la clase que puede ver [en la actualizacion de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/191523/c%C3%B3mo-saber-qu%C3%A9-parte-de-una-lista-que-representa-un-%C3%A1rbol-est%C3%A1-contenida-o-es-s) quiero  crear diferentes instancias de una clase con un bucle. Intenté el siguiente :

```
objs = [WordTree(sent, sent[0].label()) for sent in enumerate(sentences)]
```

`sentences` esta oraciones separadas por `en_nlp` :

```
['Beyoncé Giselle Knowles-Carter (/biːˈjɒnseɪ/ bee-YON-say) (born September 4, 1981) is an American singer, songwriter, record producer and actress.', "Born and raised in Houston, Texas, she performed in various singing and dancing competitions as a child, and rose to fame in the late 1990s as lead singer of R&B girl-group Destiny's Child.", "Managed by her father, Mathew Knowles, the group became one of the world's best-selling girl groups of all time.", 'Their hiatus saw the release of Beyoncé\'s debut album, Dangerously in Love (2003), which established her as a solo artist worldwide, earned five Grammy Awards and featured the Billboard Hot 100 number-one singles "Crazy in Love" and "Baby Boy".']
```

Sin embargo, cuando hago la instanciación no tengo nada.

```
>>>objs = [WordTree(sent, sent[0].label()) for sent in enumerate(sentences)]
>>>objs
[]
```